# json ajax update HTML element not working

Tags: php, json, ajax

I am trying to get a HTML element to update from an ajax quire to a PHP file but it's not working.
My code is below

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<script>
var json = (function () {
 var json = null;
    $.ajax({
      url: "test.php",
      dataType: "json", //the return type data is jsonn
      success: function(data){ // <--- (data) is in json format
        json = data.test;
  $('#demo').text(json.test1);
 }
  });
  return json;
 })();
</script>
<p id="demo"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP code

```
 <?php
 header("Content-Type: application/json");

 $test = array();
 $test['test1'] = '1';
 $test['test2'] = '2';
 $test['test3'] = '3';

 echo json_encode($test);
 //echo nothing after this //not even html
 ?>
```

can someone please help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your php script sending a `JSON` object and you can access its property like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "test.php",
  dataType: "json", //the return type data is jsonn
  success: function(data){ // <--- (data) is in json format
    $('#demo').text(data.test1);
}
});
```

Comment: thanks this worked, i was thinking I had to put it into a variable.

Answer (score 0):

the Javascript is the problem. You should bind the function that makes the AJAX query to a DOM event, such as a button click.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#submit").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({type: "POST",
            url: "test.php",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { name: $("#name").val()},
            success:function(data){         
                $("#demo").text(data.test1);
            }
    });
  });
});
</script>

<input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name">
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

On PHP side, you can read the input:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");

$test = [
   'test1'=>1, 'test2'=>2, 'test3'=>3, 'name'=>$_POST['name']
];
echo json_encode($test);
exit;
```

Comment: I don't want a click function, my aim is for the ajax to update the html element at set intervals. I am very news to this so I a trying to get this to work and then add onto it.

Comment: @user2669997 I understand.  Good luck.